# Access files from ubuntu live cd

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive

i just have a ubuntu live cd for some critical situations...
I have a vaio F11 and a win10 as OS on it,but  windows can't boot from HDD, so I tried to access files using ubuntu live,but it says:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/14FCB981FCB95E24: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/ubuntu/14FCB981FCB95E24"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

now please help me on this,I have some important data on my HDD...show me if there is anyway to copy them on an external HDD.

Comment: Seriously... you can not boot Windows and Microsoft has not a generic solution to fix that problem so you need to use Ubuntu live session?  I sort of doubt that. If you use the " remove hiber file" command we have be warned: you -will- destroy any data on that partition that is in the hiberfile and not saved to disk.

Comment: even i tried this : mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows but it didnt work

Comment: is there any way to copy files from hdd to an external hdd in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

`mount` requires using sudo and supplying proper settings for mounting. What I suggest is that you use `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY`, where X is letter of your drive and Y is the partition number. It will be mounted automatically to `/media` directory, the exact mountpoint will be printed to the screen (`stdout`).

Sample process from my system:

1) Determine the  partition letter and number with `sudo blkid` or `sudo lsblk -f`

```
xieerqi:$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="86df21bf-d95f-435c-9292-273bdbcba056" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System" UUID="F4F688B2F68876A0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="TI105866W0A" UUID="4EBAAE53BAAE36FD" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="HDDRECOVERY" UUID="BC4ED40D4ED3BDF8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="3a6e2270-19a2-49d7-aab3-5efb92d3b3d0" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="6A32C4555E1C5B4D" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="BA02-AF80" TYPE="vfat"
```

2) Run the `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY` command to mount your desired partition.

```
xieerqi:$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
Mounted /dev/sdb2 at /media/xieerqi/TI105866W0A.
```

3) Navigate to the mount point with `cd /media/user/mountpoint` or use GUI file manager.

4) When done, unmount the partition.

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb2                                                                                              
Unmounted /dev/sdb2.
```